# Nginx Rewrite Convert Querystring to Path

Tags: nginx, rewrite, querystring

I whould like this simple rewrite rule:

```
/somefolder/mypage.aspx?myid=4343&tab=overview
```

to be redirected to:

```
/folder/4343/overview/
```

I looked for some solutions and none actually worked..

I tried:

```
rewrite ^/somefolder/mypage.aspx?myid=(.*)&tab=overview$  /folder/$1/overview  permanent;
```

and

```
rewrite ^/somefolder/mypage\.aspx\?myid=(.*)&tab=overview$  /folder/$1/overview  permanent;
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm getting 404

(simpler rules works just fine..)

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want redirect

```
location ~ /somefolder/mypage.aspx {
    if ($args ~* "^myid=(\d+)&tab=overview") {
        set $mid $1;
        set $args '';
        rewrite ^.*$ /folder/$mid/overview permanent;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to configure /folder/$1/overview location.

Comment: Thanks, the redirect works, but without the paramater ($1)... it is blank

Comment: I updated answer.

Answer (score 38):

A shorter and more correct version of Valery Viktorovsky answer.

```
location = /somefolder/mypage.aspx {
    if ($arg_tab != overview) { return 404; }
    if ($arg_myid !~ "^\d+$") { return 404; }
    rewrite ^ /folder/$arg_myid/overview? permanent;
}
```

Or, hey, it can even be shorter, if you don't need to be verifying the arguments:

```
rewrite ^/somefolder/mypage.aspx /folder/$arg_myid/$arg_tab? permanent;
```

Comment: wish you had posted it earlier :) it would've save me some time

Comment: lol.  did you have a lot of rules like that?  well, better late than never!  also, can i get an accept, then? :)

Comment: Valery solution works bottom line :) and there could be only one answer :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work « *Make sure that besides working for you, the answer is really good practice. Sometimes after the answer gets accepted, another comes in, uncovering the fact that previous one was in fact a bad hack.* »  Seriously, there are not just one, but a several different problems with Valery's answer!  Every line is essentially wrong, other than the curly braces!