# nginx rewrite of url with query string

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have been googling for a good while and can't figure this one out.  It seems simple, and I am sure it is, but I am not a server expert.

My url is: `http://www.example.com/blog/?tag=Word1+Word2`

Some of the  tags are a single word (ex: bicycle), some are longer (ex: Two wheel bicycle).

I need this url to be output as: `example.com/blog/tag/word1-word2/`

How can I get a rewrite to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx Rewrite Convert Querystring to Path](http://serverfault.com/questions/488444/nginx-rewrite-convert-querystring-to-path)

Comment: I had looked at that one.  The question I come back to is that /blog/ is the root of my blog.  Those responses in that other post all have /location/file.asmx.  I need the blog to work, and post urls like /blog/post-title/.

Comment: `Some of the tags are a single word, some are longer.` — what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should send - in your query instead of + to get same format and make an easier request :

```
location ~ /blog/ {
    if ($args ~* "tag=(.*)") {
        set $w1 $1;
        rewrite .* /blog/tag/$w1/? permanent;
    }
}
```

Based on the link i posted

`?` at the end will remove the query string parameters (from [rewrite doc](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite)  )

> If you specify a ? at the end of a rewrite then Nginx will drop the original $args (arguments)

another to achieve it is to set args to nothing:

```
set $args '';
```

Comment: I tried variations on that and got 404's. what happens if the tag is only a single word like "bicycle"?

Comment: in this case it will not works, so try first with 2 words, if it work i will modify to works for your case. Are there max 2 words, or can it be (n) words ?

Comment: it can be (n) words.  It did not work when I tested on a two word tag.   The rewrite you have there resulted in this url: http://www.urlt.com/blog/tag/-/?tag=Reliance+Nitro

Comment: ok i did some change can you confirm it works now with 2 parameters ?

Comment: that resulted in: http://www.url.com/blog/tag/-/

Comment: Answer edited to work